# Total Count of Posts NOT in Selected Categories?

Tags: query-posts, wp-query

I need to get the total number of posts that are not in selected categories.
I have category IDs of the categories that I want to exclude from count (in the variable `$folio_cat_ids`)

So far I have this code which is not working,

```
$numposts = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts 
  WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
    AND post_type = 'post' 
    AND post_name NOT LIKE '%revision%' 
    AND post_name NOT LIKE '%autosave%' 
    AND post_category NOT IN($folio_cat_ids)");
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Do your posts have multiple categories? If not - I think individual category counts are cached, so can sum up counts:

```
$categories = get_categories( array( 'exclude' => $folio_cat_ids ) );

$count = 0;
foreach ( $categories as $category)
    $count += $category->category_count;
```

Can also just get and count the posts, that is more flexible and takes care of overlap, but also more resource-intensive:

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'category__not_in' => $folio_cat_ids,
    'numberposts' => '-1'
) );

$count = count( $posts );
```

Comment: I am always getting same result, even if i have different categories in $folio_cat_ids. Are the objects cached or something. Although I am using wp_reset_query already. (I am using the second code as I have posts with multiple categories for some posts)

Comment: In which format do you have categories stored in variable? `category__not_in` only takes an array of IDs.

Comment: yes it has comma separated list of category IDs

Comment: Comma separated list is `string`, you need `array` for this argument. So do something like `explode( ',', $folio_cat_ids );` to use it with `category__not_in`.

Comment: @Rarst - Calling `get_posts()` to return all posts is very heavy just to get a count, especially when there are lots of posts. In WP 3.1 *I think* there will be arguments that allow you to get a `COUNT(*)` without having to use a hook, but it's not here yet.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel yep, I understand that and mentioned in my answer. But sometimes it is easier go with API (low amount of items, additional caching layer, etc) then write custom code for minor tasks.

Comment: @Rarst - For a small number of posts, true. Although this one is easy since it only needs a `'post_fields'` hook; it can get much more complicated with other requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@Rich**:

Welcome to WordPress Answers.

The `'post_category'` field is not used anymore and has been replaced by a collection of *"taxonomy"* tables. If you were using direct SQL it would look like this:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  {$wpdb->posts} 
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id={$wpdb->posts}.ID
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id={$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish' 
  AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'post' 
  AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_name NOT LIKE '%revision%' 
  AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_name NOT LIKE '%autosave%' 
  AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id NOT IN ($folio_cat_ids)
SQL;
$numposts = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
```

However, it's a good idea to use the WordPress API rather than direct SQL if you can avoid having to write lots of SQL when using the WordPress API, which in this case is very possible. I've written a small class for you called `CountPostsCategoriesNotIn` which encapsulates the `'posts_fields'` hook you need to use. Calling this class is as simple as this:

```
$folio_cat_ids = '1,2,3';
$numposts = CountPostsCategoriesNotIn::count($folio_cat_ids);
echo "$numposts\n";
```

And here is that class which you can copy into your theme's `functions.php` file or use in the `.php` file of a plugin you might be writing:

```
class CountPostsCategoriesNotIn {
  static function count($categories) {
    $posts_fields = array(__CLASS__,'posts_fields');
    add_action('posts_fields',$posts_fields);
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
      'posts_per_page' => '-1',
      'category__not_in' => $categories,
    ));
    remove_action('posts_fields',$posts_fields);
    return $query->post->post_count;
  }
  static function posts_fields($field_list) {
    $field_list = 'COUNT(*) as post_count';
    return $field_list;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir, Thanks a lot for solution. Can you please post a non OOP version of the code, just a function I mean. I have just started to learn OO PHP and I don't have enough knowledge to convert it into a basic function. Like when you populate $posts_fields in the first line, I don't get it :(

Comment: @RichZenMaster - The `$posts_fields` is the *"callable"* value used by `add_action()` to find the hook to run (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php); I put in a variable for when I later do `remove_action()` but it's just a convenience and would have done w/o OOP. Being pedantic, this isn't OOP, it's just using a class to encapsulate `$posts_fields` so you won't need a cryptic function name to minimize conflicts. It is a self-contained drop in, why do you need a basic function instead?  If you still need a function I can, but this is a better approach.